# php mail + utf-8 = problem in Internet explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, utf-8

I have a form on a page that sends data to php file via ajax request. The data is then collected into a single variable and sent to email specified in the php file. The data is in slovenian an uses a lot of letters that use diacritics (š,ć,ž). Everything works fine when the form is submitted from any browser that isn't Internet Explorer, but when sent from IE, email contains some gibberish charachters instead of letters with diacritics...

I specified mail headers in php file like this:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: xxx@yyy.si' . "\r\n";
```

the form is:

```
        <form id="order" class="order" name="form299" action="orderForm.php" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
             <p>Ime Priimek / Naziv 

    podjetja:</p>

 .....   
         <p>Naslov / Sedež podjetja:</p>
```

Did anyone encounter this problem?

Comment: Could you specify what version of IE you are using? Please also specify, in what encoding you send the form to the browser?

Comment: did you check it without emailing, just by direct output or storing into text file?

Comment: @ZeissS : It's the same in any version of IE
@Col.Shrapnel : I'll try that, but I don't think that would do anything since the mail arrives as it should when sent from any other browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cause of this problem, it's urlencoding in javascript... Beginner's mistake :)

I just added

```
encodeURI('element.value')
```

for each field that I am sending via ajax, and it worked perfectly